# WinForms exception interceptor

Tags: winforms, asynchronous, exception, interceptor, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using the ABP framework with WinForms and I need to identify the best way to intercept an exception and log this information.

My WinForms is a Multiple-Document Interface (MDI) application. I add a `HandleException` in **Program.cs** so that when the application throws an exception, I'm able to log it in the log file. But if I get an exception in an `ApplicationService`, this exception is handled by ABP and not thrown back to WinForms, and nothing is written in the log file.

Do I need to implement some interface to have the classic logging like MVC/Angular app?

**UPDATE**

I found that the problem is related to async operation. Usually I call:

```
await _service.GetProducts();
```

If an exception is thrown, the main thread does not intercept it. If I switch to:

```
AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _service.GetProducts());
```

Then the main thread intercepts the error.

Answer (score 0):

because the exception is thrown in another thread you have to handle unhandled exceptions of the application domain. insert the exception handler into the starting point of your application. for win forms i guess you can use program.cs

```
static class Program
{
  [STAThread]
  static void Main(string[] argv)
  {
    try
    {
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender,e)
      => HandleException(e.ExceptionObject);

      Application.ThreadException += (sender,e)
      => HandleException(e.Exception);


      Application.Run(new MainWindow());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      HandleException(ex);
    }
  }

  static void HandleException(object exception) {
    var ex= exception as Exception;
    if (ex== null) {
         ex= new NotSupportedException("Unhandled exception: " + exceptionObject.ToString());
    }

    //you can log exception here -> ex.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: @Albert thk for your suggestion but in this way you cannot intercept async exception

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some invastigation and googling I found this MSDN explanation [Asynchronous Programming - Async from the Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt620013.aspx)

Accoriding to this article I change my program start to move to async code. 
I need to chage a little bit more because I'm on Mdi Form when open a inside form

```
Form1 childForm = Globals.Bootstrapper.IocManager.Resolve<Form1>();
        childForm.MdiParent = this;
        var formAsync = childForm.InitializeAsync();
        FormExtension.HandleExceptions(formAsync);
        childForm.Show();
```

I add the static class to intercept the error form Abp

```
public static async void HandleExceptions(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Yield(); //ensure this runs as a continuation
            await task;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //deal with exception, either with message box
            //or delegating to general exception handling logic you may have wired up 
            //e.g. to Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.UnhandledException
            var log = Globals.Bootstrapper.IocManager.IocContainer.Resolve<ILogger>();
            LogHelper.LogException(log, ex);
            //Exception handling...
            MessageBox.Show("Ops!" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            //Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Now my log file is populated in correct way

Comment: this doesn't look like a convient way of achieving the problem. where's the interception here? you just create a try-catch surrounding over task. in an interception you have to do something before or after the actual function!